# Get machine name from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I have performed an "LDAP://" query to get a list of computers within a specified OU, my issue is not being able to collect just the computer "name" or even "cn".

```
        DirectoryEntry toShutdown = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + comboBox1.Text.ToString());
        DirectorySearcher machineSearch = new DirectorySearcher(toShutdown);
        //machineSearch.Filter = "(objectCatergory=computer)";
        machineSearch.Filter = "(objectClass=computer)";
        machineSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
        machineSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");
        SearchResultCollection allMachinesCollected = machineSearch.FindAll();
        Methods myMethods = new Methods();
        string pcName;
        foreach (SearchResult oneMachine in allMachinesCollected)
        {
            //pcName = oneMachine.Properties.PropertyNames.ToString();
            pcName = oneMachine.Properties["name"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(pcName);
        }
```

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can upgrade to .NET 3.5, I would definitely recommend doing so.

With .NET 3.5, you get a new `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace which makes a lot of these takes much easier.

To find all computers and enumerate them, you'd do something like this:

```
// define a domain context - use your NetBIOS domain name
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");

// set up the principal searcher and give it a "prototype" of what you want to
// search for (Query by Example) - here: a ComputerPrincipal
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher();
srch.QueryFilter = new ComputerPrincipal(ctx);;

// do the search
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = srch.FindAll();

// enumerate over results
foreach(ComputerPrincipal cp in results)
{
   string computerName = cp.Name;
}
```

Check out the [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) on MSDN Magazine for more information on the new `S.DS.AM` namespace and what it offers.

If you can't move up to .NET 3.5 - you just need to keep in mind that the `.Properties["name"]` that you get from the search result is a **collection of values** - so in order to grab the actual pc name, use this:

```
pcName = oneMachine.Properties["name"][0].ToString();
```

You need to index the `.Properties["name"]` collection with a `[0]` to get the first entry (typically also the only entry - hardly any computer has more than one name).

Comment: I just added the [0] in before i read your post, worked like a treat :) Thanks again Marc.

Im going to have to do some reading up on the collections e.g. Properties, as i don't really understand what they are yet, or how to work out when im dealing with a collection of objects.

Comment: I am actually using .Net 3.5 i just didn't have the foggiest idea about how to use the .AccountManagement namespace, though it will be something i have a look at as i hope to extend the app i'm writing when i get some more time, for now the bare minimum will do as i need it Monday :)

Comment: @Stephen Murby: definitely read the MSDN article - excellent stuff!